# Deeplinking to ubereats app ratings page

Tags: uber-api

I would like to set a link in a message to send to my uberEats customers  that would take them to their apps last order where they could rate and tip the customer. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an uberEATS API or public deeplink schema, so at this point this is not available. I believe deeplinks like you describe is something that the EATS team is interested in doing, however, so stay tuned in the second half of this year.